# How to set iframe min-height so it stays from header to footer or longer?

Tags: html, css, iframe, layout

I have this structure of page. I need the iframe tag to fill whole screen height from header to footer or longer (purple part). So far it has limited height.

http://jsfiddle.net/isadykov/s37z0pfu/39/

```css
body, html, form {padding:0; margin:0; height:100%;}
#header, #footer{width:100%; background:#ccc; text-align:center;}
#header {height: 30px;}
#footer {height: 20px;}
#content{height: calc(100% - 30px);}
#leftMenu {width:200px; float:left; height:100%;}
#westNorth {width:200px; overflow-y:auto; position: fixed; top:30px;bottom:70px;background:aqua;}
#westSouth {width:200px; height:70px; position: fixed; bottom:0px;  background: pink;}
#rightcol {overflow-y:auto; height: 100%;  background:green;}
#rightcontent {min-height:100%; margin: 0 auto -20px;background:magenta;}
#push {height: 20px;}
#Mainpanel {width:99%; height:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="header"> header content </div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="leftMenu">    
    <div id="westNorth">left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />
       left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />
    </div>
    <div id="westSouth">
       left bottom content<br />left bottom content<br />left bottom content<br />
    </div>     
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <div id="rightcontent">          
       <iframe id="Mainpanel" src="https://www.desmos.com/fourfunction"  ></iframe>    
      <div id="push" ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> footer content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need functionality as in [this structure](http://jsfiddle.net/isadykov/s37z0pfu/40/), but instead of text in div with `id=rightcontent` should be iframe tag. As you can see the "footer" staying in the bottom if tag div with `id=rightcontent` (purple) is shorter than height of screen. If `rightcontent` is longer than screen height then footer pushed to bottom of page. I need the same but with iframe.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @Ihazkode, yes, I am using jquery but I would like to do that with css. Anyway if I will not be able to find solution with css then as the last resort I'll take a look at jqury.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the position of the rightcontent and footer to relative, and make the iframe absolute in order the be able to expand to its parent height and width.

```css
body, html, form {padding:0; margin:0; height:100%;}
#header, #footer{width:100%; background:#ccc; text-align:center;}
#header {height: 30px;}
#footer {height: 20px; position: relative;}
#content{height: calc(100% - 30px);}
#leftMenu {width:200px; float:left; height:100%;}
#westNorth {width:200px; overflow-y:auto; position: fixed; top:30px;bottom:70px;background:aqua;}
#westSouth {width:200px; height:70px; position: fixed; bottom:0px;  background: pink;}
#rightcol {overflow-y:auto; height: 100%;  background:green;}
#rightcontent {min-height: 100vh; border: none; margin: 0 auto -20px;background:magenta; position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
#push {height: 20px;}
#Mainpanel {width:100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; display: block; overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<div id="header"> header content </div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="leftMenu">    
    <div id="westNorth">left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />
       left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />left top content<br />
    </div>
    <div id="westSouth">
       left bottom content<br />left bottom content<br />left bottom content<br />
    </div>     
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <div id="rightcontent">          
       <iframe id="Mainpanel" src="https://www.desmos.com/fourfunction"  ></iframe>    
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> footer content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why there are two scrollbars and the footer overlapping content and not pushed to bottom of page?

Comment: @Ildar One is from Desmos (Iframe), the second one was a mistake just fixed it. Hope it helps.

Comment: how to stick the footer to the bottom of page so it is visible only after scrolling to very bottom? So far it is in bottom of screen and always visible.

Comment: @Ildar Try this new one! Added: Overflow: hidden so you cant scroll on iframe but you can scroll on the right panel.

Comment: I still see two scrollbars. The footer is appearing only after scrolling even the height of content is shorter than screen.  If the height of content is shorter of screen then footer should be visible at the bottom of screen as in the example http://jsfiddle.net/isadykov/s37z0pfu/40/ Try to make the height of screen longer than the height of content and shorter and watch after footer. After the scree is higher than content the footer just will stay on the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
#Mainpanel {width:99%; height:100%;}
```

to

```
#Mainpanel {width:99%; height:100vh;}
```

Comment: There are two scrollbars. Should be only one. If #Mainpanel {width:99%; height:calc(100vh - 50px);} then the footer will stay on the bottom of screen. It should be pushed to bottom of page if content is longer than screen height.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Mainpanel {width:99%; height:88%;position:absolute}
#footer{
  position:relative;bottom:0;
}
```

set the height as your requirement and position: absolute;
Hope this will work fine.
For any query please write comment

Comment: The footer shouldn't stay on the same position and overlapping with content.

Comment: you want say that footer will be above the iframe and at time bottom.

Comment: the footer is attached to the end of content. The footer should stay on the bottom of screen if content is shorter of screen. If content longer than height of screen then the footer should be on the bottom of page so it is visible after scrolling. Take a look at my second link to example of functionality http://jsfiddle.net/isadykov/s37z0pfu/40/ and try to make the height of screen higher or shorter.